# Creating Custom function for iterating summary

Tags: r, function

I have created a algorithm to get a summary of list of subsets.

Here is my data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Name = c("asdf", "kjhgf", "cvbnm", "rtyui", "cvbnm", "jhfd", "cvbnm", "sdfghj", "cvbnm", "dfghj", "cvbnm"),
  sale = c(27,NA, 27, 16, 14,NA, 14, 14,NA, 18, 28),
  city = c("CA", "TX", "MN", "NY", "TX", "MT", "HU", "KL", "TX", "SA", "TX"),
  Dept = c("HH", "MM", "NN", "MM", "AA", "VV", "MM", "HU", "JJ", "MM", "ZZ")
)
```

Now I have created some subsets as requirement:

```
df1<- df
df$cc1<-1
#Astellas
df2<- subset(df, Dept == 'MM')
df$cc2<-ifelse(df$Dept == 'MM',1,NA)
lst<-list(df$cc1, df$cc2)
ldat<-list("ALL" = df1, "MM" =df2)
```

With the algorithm below, I am able to get the desired summary output but I want to create a function that does the same. Please help find out how to create a custom function to get same results as the script below.

```
df %>%
  select(-Name, -city) %>%
  group_by(Dept) -> dat

  N <- length(dat[[1]])
  Median <- median(dat[[1]])
  Average <- mean(dat[[1]])
  q25 <- quantile(dat[[1]])[2]
  q75 <- quantile(dat[[1]])[4]
  cbind(q25, Median, Average, q75, N) -> ALL
  dat %>% filter(Dept == "MM") -> MM
  N <- length(MM[[1]])
  Median <- median(MM[[1]])
  Average <- mean(MM[[1]])
  q25 <- quantile(MM[[1]])[2]
  q75 <- quantile(MM[[1]])[4]
  cbind(q25, Median, Average, q75, N) -> MM
  as.data.frame(rbind(ALL, MM)) %>%
  `rownames<-`(., c("ALL", "MM")) %>%
    pander::pander() %>% as.data.frame()
```

I need to convert the above script into a function like this:

```
functiont(data=ldat,var = "sale", name_of_var = c("ALL","MM"))
```

The function should be dynamic for list of variables. In this case we have two variable `c("ALL" ,"MM")`. so this should be dynamic.

The output summary should be a `flextable` like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("asdf","kjhgf","cvbnm","rtyui","cvbnm","jhfd","cvbnm","sdfghj","cvbnm","dfghj","cvbnm"),
                 sale=c(27,28,27,16,14,25,14,14,19,18,28),
                 city=c("CA","TX","MN","NY","TX","MT","HU","KL","TX","SA","TX"),
                 Dept = c("HH","MM","NN","MM","AA","VV","MM","HU","JJ","MM","ZZ"))


df1<- df
df$cc1<-1
df2<- subset(df, Dept == 'MM')
df$cc2<-ifelse(df$Dept == 'MM',1,NA)
lst<-list(df$cc1, df$cc2)
listd<-list("ALL" = df1, "MM" =df2)

#I want to run my function for listd so that i can get a  combined summary for all variables in listd
tt2<-function(data,var,footer,Name_of_variable,decimal){
  for (d in 1:length(data)) {
    cat('\n\n#### ', names(data)[d], '\n\n')
    md<-data[[d]]
    table_list<-list()
    for (i in 1:length(d))
      table_list[[i]]<-t1(md,var,footer,decimal,Name_of_variable)
    tt<- do.call(rbind,table_list)
  } 
  cat(knit_print(tt))
  cat('\n\n')
}
```

Comment: i am able to summary in Rmarkdown while using this function, but parallel summaries

Answer (score 1):

After checking your code, a function for what you want is possible. The function in the present solution takes the desired arguments but I have slightly modified to use only one dataframe, which is the main `df`. The reason is that `ALL` summaries will always come from the first big dataframe so there is no need of having a list for the global dataframe and then other object for the filter. The function produces what you want and it can admit any filters as you mentioned. Here the code of the function and some applications:

```
library(dplyr)
#Function
myfun <- function(data,var, name_of_var)
{
  #Data
  dat <- data
  #Compute for all items
  N <- length(dat[[var]])
  Median <- median(dat[[var]])
  Average <- mean(dat[[var]])
  q25 <- quantile(dat[[var]])[2]
  q75 <- quantile(dat[[var]])[4]
  as.data.frame(cbind(q25, Median, Average, q75, N)) -> ALL
  rownames(ALL) <- 'All'
  #Now the filter values
  dat %>% filter(Dept %in% name_of_var) -> MM
  #Create list
  List <- split(MM,MM$Dept)
  #Apply summaries in a function
  compute <- function(x)
  {
    N <- length(x[[var]])
    Median <- median(x[[var]])
    Average <- mean(x[[var]])
    q25 <- quantile(x[[var]])[2]
    q75 <- quantile(x[[var]])[4]
    as.data.frame(cbind(q25, Median, Average, q75, N)) -> y
    rownames(y) <- unique(x$Dept)
    return(y)
  }
  #Apply
  List2 <- do.call(rbind,lapply(List,compute))
  #Bind all
  Binded <- rbind(ALL,List2)
  return(Binded)
}
```

Now, some applications:

```
#Apply function 1
Ex1 <- myfun(data=df,var = "sale", name_of_var = c("MM"))
```

Output:

```
     q25 Median  Average  q75  N
All 15.0     19 20.90909 27.0 11
MM  15.5     17 19.00000 20.5  4
```

Example 2:

```
#Apply function 2
Ex2 <- myfun(data=df,var = "sale", name_of_var = c("MM","HH"))
```

Output:

```
     q25 Median  Average  q75  N
All 15.0     19 20.90909 27.0 11
HH  27.0     27 27.00000 27.0  1
MM  15.5     17 19.00000 20.5  4
```

After that you can format the outputs as you wish in any style.

Comment: Thanks for your precious time to look into my question, I have some observations 
1) How to handle if NA value if Var have NA in dataframe
2) name_of_var = c("ALL","MM"))  should be dynamic in function , because i have have many other subsets or cuts.
3)  data= ldat should be ldat
because I am using this function in RMD file, and I have  approx.  128 entries  for this  function

and I am defining   "Now I have created some subsets as requirement"  subsets common for all chunks , i have many more functions like this

Comment: the approach can be  like dynamically select var, and mutated columns,
and then filter subsets for those list of variables and then iterate the function for those list of variables and merge all summaries.

Comment: I have just posted my previous approach below as answer , but that was giving two parallel summaries.
so if you have any idea in that function , please check.